# How to solve a circulation and demand problem with Ford-Fulkson if there is a lower bound for outgoing flow from a node?

Tags: algorithm, graph, network-flow

Instead of having an edge that requires a lower bound to flow through, is there a way to tweak the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm to solve a circulation and demand problem where a node must have a flow going outside towards other nodes? Note that this is also in addition to needing to consider the maximum capacity on each edge as well.

Comment: What is the difference between "an edge that requires a lower bound to flow through" and "a node must have a flow going outside towards other nodes"?  In 2nd case, just move the bound from the node to the edge from the node.

Comment: There’s a [standard transformation](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs498dl1/sp2015/notes/25-maxflowext.pdf) you can do that transforms a flow problem with lower bounds to a flow problem in a different network. Perhaps this is what you’re looking for?